# Organize list of publications according to type of article

Tags: bibtex, natbib, tufte

With the `tufte-book` template (which uses `natbib`), I'd like to include at the end of the document a list of my publications, organized by type: I'd like to have a section for conference papers and one for conference posters.

How can I do it? Also, should I add some kind of mark in the .bib file to recognize posters more easily?

For now I simply have a page with all publications, with no sections:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\lipsum[1-9]

\begingroup
\renewcommand\refname{List of Publications}
\input{my_publications.bbl}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

This is my_publications.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{list_of_my_publications}
\end{document}
```

And this is list_of_my_publications.bib:

```
@inproceedings{poster1,
  title={Title of first poster},
  author={Twain, Mark and Shakespeare, William},
  booktitle={Proceedings of some workshop},
  pages={157--158},
  year={2014},
}

@inproceedings{poster2,
  title={Title of second poster},
  author={Twain, Mark and Shakespeare, William},
  booktitle={Proceedings of some other workshop},
  year={2015}
}

@inproceedings{conference_paper1,
  title={Title of first paper},
  author={Twain, Mark and Shakespeare, William},
  booktitle={Proceedings of some conference},
  pages={10--19},
  year={2015},
}


@inproceedings{conference_paper2,
  title={Title of second paper},
  author={Twain, Mark and Shakespeare, William},
  booktitle={Proceedings of some other conference},
  year={2016},
}
```

Comment: This would be pretty easy with Biblatex/Biber. But why are you inputting the `.bbl`? In that case, you are not using BibTeX/natbib at all at this point (except for citations in the text). Also, please provide a complete minimal example. Without `my_publications.bbl`, nobody can compile your code. But probably you should give us a couple of sample entries in a `.bib` and set the example up that way, assuming you are not really just inputting a hand-written `.bbl`.

Comment: Ok, I added the full code.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. But why are you inputting the `.bbl`?

Comment: No particular reason! I was looking for ways to add a list of publications from a separate .bib file and found that solution.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you would need to adjust the style of the bibliography according to your desiderata, but here's a basic schema. The entries are classified using `entrysubtype` in the `.bib` and `subtype` is then used to filter the entries when printing the bibliography. `natbib=true` is a compatibility option. `nobib` tells the class not to actually load `natbib`. `defernumbers=true` stops the numbering in the bibliographies being strange. Whether you need it or not will depend on the style you use. See Biblatex's documentation for details.

Compilation sequence: `pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex -> pdflatex`. Your preferred engine can be substituted for pdfTeX e.g. `latex` or `lualatex` rather than `pdflatex`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{poster1,
  title={Title of first poster},
  author={Twain, Mark and Shakespeare, William},
  booktitle={Proceedings of some workshop},
  pages={157--158},
  year={2014},
  entrysubtype={poster},
}

@inproceedings{poster2,
  title={Title of second poster},
  author={Twain, Mark and Shakespeare, William},
  booktitle={Proceedings of some other workshop},
  year={2015},
  entrysubtype={poster},
}

@inproceedings{conference_paper1,
  title={Title of first paper},
  author={Twain, Mark and Shakespeare, William},
  booktitle={Proceedings of some conference},
  pages={10--19},
  year={2015},
  entrysubtype={paper},
}

@inproceedings{conference_paper2,
  title={Title of second paper},
  author={Twain, Mark and Shakespeare, William},
  booktitle={Proceedings of some other conference},
  year={2016},
  entrysubtype={paper},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\lipsum[1-9]

\nocite{*}
\renewcommand\bibname{List of Publications}
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[subtype=poster,heading=subbibliography,title=Posters]
\printbibliography[subtype=paper,heading=subbibliography,title=Papers]

\end{document}
```

[image: split bibliography]

Comment: Thanks! I see that you load the file as the bibliography with `\bibliography{\jobname}`. I forgot to say it before (my bad!), but I have a proper bibliography in the document. What I need is an additional page loading my publications from a separate .bib file and structured with the two sections I described before. Will your solution still work?

Comment: You could use `refsegment`s or `refsection`s for this purpose. Then you can specify separate groups of `.bib` files for each. I guess my advice would be to try it, taking a look at Biblatex's manual. If you get stuck, post a new question with an MWE which reflects the structure and a link back to this question/answer for reference. But, yes, it can (almost) certainly work. Biblatex is much easier to customise and much more flexible on this than BibTeX.